# PVC ring Shut off valve?

Tags: plumbing, pvc, pex, shutoff

I just bought a house built in 1984 it has PEX plumbing. I need to remove a toilet to install a new floor and I noticed the water supply line to the toilet connects to a water shut off valve that I’ve never seen before. It looks like a PVC bonnet or nut cap thing With a half crescent ring that you turn left or right to turn the water on or off.

Are these reliable or should I replace with a quarter turn ball valve. I really don’t want to do anything unnecessary but a PVC shut off valve gives me anxiety as an inexperienced DIY homeowner

[image: Valve]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PEX Line Toilet Water Supply Disconnect](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/183498/pex-line-toilet-water-supply-disconnect)

Comment: @solar mike , Since it is the same OP asking the question I do not think it is helpful.

Comment: @EdBeal perhaps it would have been better to improve / edit the original question, seems 3 agree...

Comment: Probably those that did not take the time to read both and 4 VTC.